# Multilevel hierarchical simulation? What model to use?

Tags: r, mixed-model, simulation, multilevel-analysis

1. The problem: I have a dataset that I think could be deemed hierarchical. Assume that there are 1-100 ids, which all can have anywhere from 1-3 sub_ids. Both the top ids can have specific features that differentiate them like budget, etc. but the sub_ids can all also have certain unique features.
2. The question: I searched far and wide but haven't been able to find a good answer on what model to use. What I would like to do is predict the change of an outcome variable at the top level (ids 1-100) based on changes to the underlying structure. I.e. What happens if you change the number of sub_ids? Let's say id 1 has two sub_ids 1+2, but now I add a 3rd. How does that impact the outcome at the id level, e.g. let's say the budget spent?

Ideally, I'd want to be able to simulate adding or taking away a sub_id, and/or changing features of the sub_id(s) to see how that would impact the id-level outcome variable.

3. Thoughts: I was initially thinking of using `lmer` in `R` from the `lme4` library, which I have used before, and build an `(g)lmer` model, but I'm not sure if that actually allows me to implement what I'm trying to do. Another thought was to essentially summarize the number of sub_ids at the id-level in a dedicated column, but that would also not allow me to switch out that id for 'a copy of itself' with an additional sub_id, rather I would have to feed new data into the model after I build it. I guess I'm looking for a model that allows me to simulate various scenarios.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

P.S. I hope my description of the data is not too vague.